# Ошибка клонирования Git репоизтория с Win сервера

Tags: git

Первый раз устанавливаю Git на 2008 R2.

Что было сделано:

1. Установлен на сервере Git
2. Установлен Bitvise SSH Server
3. На сервере создан локальный пользователь test и добавлен в группу
   администраторов
4. В настройках SSH сервера пользователю test разрешен доступ виндовому
   паролю
5. Подключение с рабочих станций по SSH работает, проблем нет
6. На сервере через Git Gui был создан репозиторий по пути
   e:\Repositories\test
7. Далее с рабочей станции выполняю в git bash

   ```
   git clone
   ssh://test@server:/e/Repositories/test
   ```
8. В ответ получаю

   > fatal: does not appear to be git repository, fatal:
   >       Could not read from remote repository

2 дня читаю форумы, не понимаю в чем ошибка, права у пользователя test на эту папку есть.

Comment: Мне кажется, двоеточие перед /e - лишнее.

Answer (score 2):

в [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436267/178576) (и комментариях к нему) всплыл корень проблемы:

> можете ли Вы клонировать проект в терминале так?
>
> `git clone ssh://test@server:/e/Repositories/test.git`
>
> В терминале Win ошибка - error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory

вероятно, нет программы `ssh` ни в одном из каталогов, определённых в переменной окружения `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

можете ли Вы клонировать проект в терминале так?

> git clone ssh://test@server:/e/Repositories/test.git

Comment: В терминале Win ошибка - error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory

В git bash аналогичная ошибка из топика

Comment: убедитесь что правильно указали путь. выполните `pwd` в директории с Вашим `test.git`

Comment: *error: cannot spawn ssh: No such file or directory* — вероятно, нет программы `ssh` ни в одном из каталогов, определённых в переменной окружения `PATH`.